# Disable sending events for @Published variables in the ObservableObject

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have problem, that UI gets ugly updated from zero to some number. *Problem is when removing all items and adding new items to array UI gets updated* because this array is marked with ***@Published*** property wrapper. More detailed explanation about problem:

1. At stage 1 (marked in the code snapshot) removing items from the list.
2. In this case UI gets updated and count in the UI updates to zero.
3. After some time when fetch is done and new items are added into array
   (stage 2).
4. Then UI gets update with new items count.
5. Problem is that here is ugly count update from zero to some number in the UI.

Is here a way to disable distributing event for class members which are marked with @Published property wrapper?

```
class ItemsProvider: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = []

    func fetchUsing(query: Query, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        self.items.removeAll() // 1. Removing old items.

        query.getDocuments { (result, error) in
            result?.forEach {
                self.items.append(try? $0.data(as: Item.self)) // 2. Adding new items.
            }
            completion(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: one possible way would be, that you store your data "first" in another place (maybe until all is loaded) and fill it to your published variable when you want the UI to be updated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't perform partial updates to `items`. Compute the entire new array before setting `items`.

```
func fetchUsing(query: Query, completion: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
    query.getDocuments { (result, error) in
        self.items = result?.compactMap { try? $0.data(as: Item.self) } ?? []
        completion(error)
    }
}
```